# How to get JSON data from hosted PHP script using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am trying to get JSON data (Locally in Xampp) from a PHP script hosted on my web host.

The PHP script is like this:

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST'); 

// Creating the data array
$data = array(
    'id' => '1',
    'url' => 'http://twitter.com',
    'text' => 'test 001',
);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

?>
```

The data it displays when run directly (http://website.com/php/script.php) from the server:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "url": "http://twitter.com",
    "text": "test 001"
}
```

And the broken HTML / JS which should output this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$.getJSON('http://website.com/php/script.php', function(data) {
  var items = [];

  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
  });

  $('<ul/>', {
    'class': 'my-new-list',
    html: items.join('')
  }).appendTo('body');
});

</script>

</head>

<body>

<span id="output"></span>

</body>
</html>
```

I run the html as a .php script in xampp, i am not sure if that makes any difference with jQuery or regular JS but most things seem fine.

How can i get back the data "1", "http://twitter.com" and "test 001" etc?

Comment: It works just fine, so if you're not getting anything, maybe your paths are wrong? Tested both the PHP script and the HTML-page now, and they both work fine (changed the path to the PHP-script, apart from that they're exactly the same).

Comment: That is odd, i am sure the paths are ok. I wonder if it is a local problem, i will try hosting it online and see what happens.

Comment: It seems to work now like you say after renaming the .php to html.

Comment: This was tested on a local server, shouldn't matter.

Comment: Also, php or html as extension shouldn't matter either, they're treated exactly the same as long as there is no PHP code in the file.

Comment: Seems like having html.php in xampp breaks it where as html.html works ok, which is kinda odd.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137293/discussion-between-zeddex-and-junkfoodjunkie).

Answer (score 0):

The problem in this case was that i was running the html as a .php file in xampp which for some reason caused it to not return any data.

After changing it to .html instead it then ran fine.

Comment: If that's the case, you have bigger problems with your server setup. No need at all for the change of extension, shouldn't make a difference. And, as tested, doesn't make a difference on my WAMP or MAMP server. Never really likes XAMPP myself, always thought it was more work than it was worth to get it up and running.